# Ajaxifying the PagedList pagination in mvc not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I'm trying to Ajaxify the paging in mvc 4 PagedList. See below output of pager html div

```
<div id="myPager">
  <div class="pagination-container">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="disabled PagedList-pageCountAndLocation"><a>Page 1 of 2.</a>/li>
      <li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a href="/Request/ManageRequest?page=2&amp;searchFilter=1&amp;RequestId=1">2</a></li>
      <li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/Request/ManageRequest?page=2&amp;searchFilter=2&amp;RequestId=2" rel="next">»</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The actual partial view has the following pagedlist mark up

```
        <div id="myPager">
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ManageRequest", new { page, searchTerm = ViewBag.SearchTerm, searchFilter = ViewBag.SearchFilter }), new PagedListRenderOptions
               {
                   EllipsesFormat = "&#8230;",
                   LinkToFirstPageFormat = "««",
                   //more options                       

               })
        </div>
```

And my controllers Action method has the following signatures

```
   public virtual PartialViewResult SearchResults(string searchTerm, string searchFilter, int? page)
    {
       //some processing
    return PartialView("_SearchResults", SearchResults.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
    }
```

And my jquery ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("SearchResults", "Request")',
            data: { searchTerm: $("#searchTerm").val(), searchFilter: $("#searchFilter").val() },

        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $('#Results').empty().html(data);

        })
        .error(function () {

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

What happens is when we click on page,r Ajax click never gets called and the control goes to the actual link as below

http://localhost:60784/Request/ManageRequest?page=2&searchFilter=RequestId

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: The information you have given is very limited. Show your View code and any other related codes.

Comment: I have added the relevant section of the partial view. In my main view I have a search box with Search button. On button click I make Ajax call to server and load the partial view with pagination. Please let me know if I shall provide more information